# Call AngularJs controller method from another Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have one common controller this controller contain one method . I need to call this controller method from another service. Is it possible.

My Example code:
This is my `Root Controller` and its contain function called `myFunction`

```
    app.controller('rootController', function($rootScope,$scope,$on) {  

    $scope.$on("func_call", function(event, args) {
    var p = args.myParam;
    // do something
})

    });
```

This is my service, from this service I need to call the function in root controller

```
 app.factory('anotherService', function($rootScope,$broadcast){

        $rootScope.$broadcast("func_call", { myParam: {} });
    });
```

I tried to call the Root Controller function from service `$rootScope.myFunction ("called")` but its not working . Any one please suggest better way to call the root controller function from service

Comment: why you want to call controller method from ?service..usually we call service method from controller

Comment: Because the service don't have any controller. that's why i need to call the controller function from service. is it possible?

Comment: look at the answer I've added.. Thanks :)

Comment: what do you want to achieve by calling a function in a controller? why can you move that function out from the controller?

Comment: See @Ivan's answer, with working demo in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179289/angularjs-broadcast-event-from-service)

Answer (score 2):

you can always use `$broadcast`, `$emit` and `$on`

try going over the [$rootScope docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

set up the receiving function listener in controller:

```
$scope.$on("func_call", function(event, args) {
    var p = args.myParam;
    // do something
})
```

and call it in your service:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("func_call", { myParam: {} });
```

Comment: How can I pass the parameter through this function call from service?

Comment: i tried to use with the `$broadcast` but im getting AngularJs injector ERROR. how can we solve this issue??

Comment: did you inject $rootScope to your controller ?

Comment: I updated my asked question can you please have a look. And one more thing i need to call the same function from the controller as well as service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77781/discussion-between-team-and-svarog).